# Unintended ion-textarea focus on ion-modal backdrop click, native keyboard showing for a short time

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, keyboard, modal-dialog, ionic5

I've been working on an app that opens a modal with a few buttons and an ion-textarea. After clicking the backdrop of the modal, the textarea would focus for a short period of time and open the native keyboard of the device, which is unintended. After looking on StackOverflow and the ionic framework forum, I didn't find a fix for this bug so I tried fixing it myself.

Eventually, I figured out that adding an ion-input to the page and hiding it from the user, prevents the modal from focussing on the textarea on modal dismiss.

This might not be the most clean fix, but it sure beats the user from seeing the keyboard for a short time when he does not click the ion-textarea element.

HTML:
`<ion-input class="keyboard-focus-bugfix"></ion-input>`

SCSS:

```
.keyboard-focus-bugfix {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: you can use Keyboard plugin on `modalDidDismiss()=>{}`

Comment: Had to aply this "patch" in order to avoid a similiar problem in which a datetimePicker from an input inside an Ionic Modal was focusing on the last element of the form every time I click on a date inside the date picker